# Designing concurrent process start and correlations with Camunda

Tags: workflow, activiti, bpmn, camunda

I am planning a simple workflow (shown in blue on the right) which should receive shipments belonging to the same order and continue the flow once all shipments have been collected.

[image]

Receiving shipments happen via REST and I plan to correlate to the right workflow instance using the order_id which is part of the request. The REST service is running in a cluster, so no in-VM locking is possible at this point.

I see two serious issues with this design:

- concurrent inbound shipment requests will fail to correlate so they will start multiple workflow instances in the same time
- even if the flow is started once successfully, Camunda will throw concurrent modification exception when simultanous shipment requests try to update the same workflow instance’s variables

How can I design this scenario to avoid these problems?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about handling the shipments in a subprocess and notify the main process once everything is shipped. Something like this:

[image]

Edit: Updated diagram based on comments.

Comment: Nice solution, but keep in mind that your event based process is interrupting, thus it completes the outer process. And though possible in camunda, using messages for intra-process communication is not supported by the spec.

Comment: I'm pretty new to BPMN, so this was just an idea I've quickly sketched in Camunda Modeler and it was obviously not tested. It should've been just a comment, but I chose an answer to convey the idea via diagram. So do you think it's a good idea to do it this way(making the message non-interrupting and sending signal instead of message at the end of subprocess)?

Comment: Yes, this is a good idea and I would have chosen a similar solution. Just make the sub-process start event non-interupting and use signal instead of message and everything is fine

Comment: I think I understand your solution clearly and sounds logical. I implemented it as above, but sending 100 parallel REST requests to the `Shipment Received` point makes Camunda fail with 

org.camunda.bpm.engine.OptimisticLockingException: ENGINE-03005 Execution of 'DELETE EventSubscriptionEntity[4c9ea600-3459-11e9-b717-0242ab803f11]' failed. Entity was updated by another transaction concurrently.
 at org.camunda.bpm.engine.impl.db.EnginePersistenceLogger.concurrentUpdateDbEntityException(EnginePersistenceLogger.java:130)

Comment: I had this issue as well. If you're running Oracle DB, you should have a look at this: https://forum.camunda.org/t/optimisticlockingexception-on-update-or-delete-of-task/5648/3

Comment: I use PostgreSQL with Camunda.

Comment: OptimisticLockingException is expected to happen in multithreaded/clustered environment(It's a performance trade off). Check this link to get some idea how to handle it: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.9/user-guide/process-engine/transactions-in-processes/#optimistic-locking

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj I understand that it's a warning message only, but right below I have this:

o.camunda.bpm.engine.context : ENGINE-16004 Exception while closing command context: Execution with id 'f7492357-3459-11e9-a3d1-0242ab803f11' does not have a subscription to a message event with name 'HelloMessage': eventSubscriptions is empty

Which sounds way worse already.

Comment: Are some of the messages processed successfully? Maybe the process ended while you were still processing incoming messages(more shipments than required).

Comment: You are right of course, this problem is gone. 

The hopefully last remaining issue is that increasing the counter is often lost, 100 parallel inbound messages took the counter only to 38, all other updates were lost..

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188721/discussion-between-kristof-jozsa-and-neplatnyudaj).